# Android NDK app builds but not runs

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://mesai0.blogspot.com/2013/01/android-native-camera-with-opencv-and.html). So far, I managed to build the project properly, both using eclipse and console. Now, I have a problem, that I can't run this project: Eclipse prompts an error `Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application`.
How can I fix this problem?
 Actually, Eclipse points to errors in `CameraRenderer.cpp` file, such as unresolved inclusions for every header file (except OpenCV headers, which is added to `jni/build` folder). Are these issues somehow connected?

I'm providing screens below.

[image: screen1]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a quick fix to just run the code for now.
You can go to the **"Problems Section"** and right click on the errors, then just delete them.
If you will make any changes to the cpp files later, you will need to re-delete them again.
So I advice you to add native support as G3M said.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do " Add Native Support" to your project to add NDK support. See the screen shot below. Right click on your project-> Android tools-> Add Native Support. [image]

Also Make sure you added path to your NDK in your properties as shown in screenshot below

[image]